# Why am not getting clear images while working in Android studio?

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-drawable, mipmaps

I am creating my app in android studio and I am using an image, if no past order present. I have imported images by `New Image Assets` method and `Android Studio` automatically loads them in various mipmaps folder according to size, but when I use those images in my `ImageView` they are shown very small and after increasing their size, they are not appearing clear, is there any way to solve this issue.

Comment: Maybe your images density is too low, try with another one that have a high density.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create "New Image Asset", make sure to select proper icon type (launcher/notification/appbar).

> Android Studio automatically loads them in various mipmaps folder
>   according to size

Image that you import into the project should be in `drawable` directory, not in the `mipmap`. Mipmap directory stores different versions of your app's launcher icons.

Also, make sure that your source image is at least big enough to fit drawable-xxhdpi size.

**EDIT:**
If you want to use your image as a background, create drawable-nodpi resourse directory (Right click on your **res** directory) and place full size image in drawable-nodpi.

Comment: Actually I need none of three(launcher, notification, appbar) I need for my background image